# Android library for booking chart / inventory chart view

Tags: android, graph, charts, timeline, inventory

I am looking for Android libraries to implement a chart view in my app. I found many useful libraries but all of them can implement line charts, bar charts or candle stick charts with only one entry per column. In my app I need to show bookings of particular inventory on a timeline. There can be multiple non overlapping entries against a single entity.

Can anyone suggest me a good library in android to solve my purpose. It would be a plus if the chart is scrollable. [This](https://github.com/trobz/openerp-booking-chart) is an implementation in python, I am looking for a similar one in android.

Thanks in advance.
Help in the growth of our community.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library:
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

It has a good documentation.

Comment: I need a library which can add individual entries to the chart like a stacked bar chart but can have empty spaces between entries. Would this be possible using MPAndroidChart?